# LTO6 drive asking firmware update but does not accept it

Tags: ibm, firmware, lto

I recently pulled an ibm LTO 6 fh fibre drive from a library and was using it in standalone mode in a windows 10 pc where I use other sas drives. It was working just fine.
Yesterday I turn it on to run some backups and notice SCD code 4 on the front. Go to ITDT software and it seems the drive is asking for a firmware update. I download the firmware automatically from said diagnostics software, and it turns out it downloads all SAS labeled versions, even when the drive is FC. F3J4.SAS_FH, K4M0.SAS_FH, and so on. I have all sas drives turned off and ITDT is not detecting them, so that should not be a problem. I try to run the update anyway and it tells me there is an error: My drive is FC and this is a SAS firmware. Run anyway? Run. Error, invalid microcode.
Then I go to the dell website (dell drives are ibm) and download the same firmware versions, but which are properly labeled as FC on dells website, but they also report microcode error.
How can I fix this? Why is the drive insisting on a firmware update when it was working fine? Should not it be optional? Currently it is on F3J4 version.
Hope to make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the PSU in the enclosure I was using. Swaped to a different one and all was fine.
Still, I had understood that the SCD was smarter at diagnosing a faulty psu, as there is even a code for that.
Thanks anyway!